# Magento 2 braintree module vault customer credit cards with separate customer ID in braintree?

Tags: magento2.3

Braintree allows to vault multiple credit cards under one customer ID.

Magento default Braintree module doesn't not work with same scenario. By default they do not send any customer ID from Magento. Use Braintree auto increment ID. I need to send Magento customer ID to Braintree which I am doing with a custom module and its working fine. But while I am trying to vault multiple credit card with Magento customer ID in Braintree getting below error:

> *Notice: Trying to get property 'status' of non-object in /var/www/magentoroot/vendor/magento/module-braintree/Gateway/Validator/ErrorCodeProvider.php
> on line 41*

Comment: Any luck on this?